# AJAX/Jquery Store dropdown value in variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my script I have the following:-

```js
<script>
      $("#country").on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("#results").html("<div class='alert-box success'><span><img src='images/shipping_ukrm.jpg'></span> <b>&pound" + selected + " plus Packaging</b></div>");
  $('#frmelement').val(selected);
      })
    </script>
```

I select the country which in turn gets the value of the option value in dropdown select field, but I want to store the dropdown value which is country name in a variable to pass and use within a form

Anyone help

This is the select dropdown box information

```html
echo '<select name="country" id="country" class="span5" />';
 echo '<option value="0" selected>Select Country</option>';
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
 $sql1 = "SELECT c.country_id,c.name,pr.price,pr.weight,pr.weight1,pr.class,c.Zone FROM country as c LEFT JOIN postagerates as pr ON pr.class = c.Zone WHERE (pr.weight <= '$totweight' AND pr.weight1 >= '$totweight') ORDER BY c.name ASC";
 $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
 while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) { 
 echo '<option value = "'.money_format('%.2n', $row2["price"]).'">'.$row2["name"].'</option>';
 }
  echo '</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text()
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mt3ag58/)

Comment: ok, that gets the selected text, how do you store this as a variable and can use it and display the data in that variable

Comment: My above code is already storing the chosen country name in the `selected` variable. I cannot know in advance where and how exactly you want to further show this variable data. You need to elaborate more.

Comment: Well I have taken the selected variable, transferred it into an input text field which is hidden and on processing of the form taken the input text value and stored in a session variable and now able to use it as and when.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code :

```php
     echo '<select name="country" id="country"  />';
     echo '<option value="0" selected>Select Country</option>';
     echo '<option value = "'.money_format('%.2n', $row2["price"]).'">'.$row2["monday"].'</option>';
 }
 echo '</select>
```

Comment: I suggest you to add some text to descrive your solution. This will make your answer more helpful (and more likely to be upvoted ;) ).